# AJAX in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I'm writing my first Codeigniter web app, and I'd like to use AJAX to pull some info for a modal box.  Can somebody guide me through an easy way to incorporate ajax w/ CI?

Specifically, the user will click on a link, and instead of being taken to another page, that page will be loaded into a modal box.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to learn ajax or just know how to make use of it in CI? Also, Kohana rocks more than CI ;)

Comment: Use of ajax in CI.  Tell me why Kohana is better.

Comment: Kohana is a group of great coders that found in CI a good base but changed many things, in order to get a better framework. Actually they take many ideas from other fw's like Cake, Symfony and others, and merge the best in their own. It's community driven, not company driven like CI, and It has so many features that it's better if you check it out at http://kohanaphp.com

Comment: except documentation is non existant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering you question, and since CI doesn't seem to have implemented yet a proper support to javascript libraries, you can use a function like this to ensure that the information you're dealing with comes from ajax :

http://snipplr.com/view/1060/check-for-ajax-request/

Note that this only works with javascript libraries like jQuery or MoonTools

After that, you just need to deal with the information as if it was a normal page, getting the data with $this->input->post('field') or $this->input->get('field') sanitized variables.

in a example (using jquery), suppose you have a anchor tag that you want to delete a row in a list of items :

```
$(function() {

  $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
  // prevents the default behaviour of the anchor
  e.preventDefault();
  // gets the id stored in the anchor as attribute
  var cid= $(this).attr('cid');

  // instantiate and executes the ajax
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.yoursite.com/ajax.php',
    data: "action=delete&cid="+cid,
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
    // alerts the response, or whatever you need
    alert(data);
  }
  });
});
```

After that, you just need to build your code in CI as a normal page. Note that I used normal url's in the ajax request (url for the base, data for the parameters), and don't know if it works properly with "url_rewrited" urls, but they might work with no problems, if you just use "url:" ajax parameter to insert the full url.

Comment: I'd really appreciate an example! :)

Comment: except instead of http://example.com/somepage.php , in CI you'd normally put in http://example.com/index.php/someclass/somemethod or http://example.com/class/method

Comment: I've modified this to work with my modal.  Thank you very much!